# Benchmarking GlusterFS & NFS on AWS using iozone and dd gives different results

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs, glusterfs, dd, iozone

I have tried benchmarking GlusterFS vs NFS on Amazon Web Services (AWS) using a m1.medium sized EC2 instance.  We use the AWS EBS as the block store, with a XFS file system.  Running Ubuntu 12.04 using the standard packages.

I used iozone and dd to do the benchmark.  I realise these are not comparable as benchmarking tools, but I am getting some strange results.

My **results in MB/s** are below (all tests are run on the client):

```
using: iozone -c -e -i 0 -+n -r 64k -s 1000M -t 2

Direct to EBS     GlusterFS     NFS       GlusterFS + NFS
37.5              26.8          99.8      21.1
```

.

```
using: dd if=/srv/test of=/dev/null bs=64k count=16k

Direct to EBS     GlusterFS     NFS       GlusterFS + NFS
97.0              40.8          58.3      23.8
```

The direct to EBS doing well using dd, but with iozone it is actually slower than NFS.  Why?

In general I have seen that GlusterFS is typically 1.5 to 2 times slower than NFS.  Are these figures realistic for GlusterFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all benchmarks it's difficult to compare apples with apples.  It appears that `iozone` thrashes the system and doesn't simulate a specific load.  `dd` just measures the throughput.

I came across [filebench](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filebench/).  With `filebench` you can simulate specific types of load, it calls these different tests "personalities".  This gave me much more realistic numbers.  I simulated a websever which typically is read only.  Although `filebench` adds a log append to the simulation, I removed this in this case.  I got the following results:

**Results in MB/s**

```
using: sudo filebench (webserver personality without simulation of log append)
Direct to EBS     GlusterFS     NFS       GlusterFS + NFS
24.2              6.0           17.0      20.4
```

Note: `filebench` was the constraint in the EBS test, since it was hogging 100% of the CPU during the test.  I presume the EBS result would be higher.

Note 2: GlusterFS by itself had a very high latency when I included the test for log append.  This may be explained in [this post](http://joejulian.name/blog/nfs-mount-for-glusterfs-gives-better-read-performance-for-small-files/).  I did not investigate this high latency issue since we expect mainly reads.